# AuthotKey: Colour detection issue

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script which shows different messages depending on if a particular shade of red or green colours are detected, at set screen coordinates. The green detection is working fine, but the red detection is not working.

The script searches the specified x and y coordinate area which is set as: x1, y1, x2, y2.

Scripts seen below.

The hex colour for the green shade is #32CD32, and for red it SEEMS to be #FF0000 (both determined by hovering over the image using Active Window Spy).

Red text screenshot:

[![Red text to be detected][1]][1]

Green text screenshot:

[![Green text that is already successfully detected][2]][2]

My script is detecting green (#32CD32) perfectly. It will NOT detect the red colour #FF0000. I have tried many different variations of the red colour, and still cannot get the script to recognize it when it is on screen. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

This second script to detect RED does not work (note that the coordinates for both scripts aren't the same- the two colours are in different places on the screen):

```
^t::
```

Am I making a mistake with the hex colour of the red text? I know that the method overall works fine for green, so it should be straightforward for red.

Comment: If the reddish `-2.4` is a representative example, the color seems to be `0xfb0019`, at least in my graphics editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code searches the specified rectangle on the screen for a *red* pixel:

```
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 121, 282, 169, 310, 0xFF0000, 3, Fast RGB
```

AutoHotKey expects colors to be specified using a Blue-Green-Red (BGR) format unless you specify the *RGB* parameter. See the documentation for [PixelSearch](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your help, that solved it- I just needed to add RGB.

Comment: Interesting coincidence that the green color had equal values for R and B and was therefore found.